# jboss 5.1 mysql connection pooling

Tags: mysql, jboss, connections, hibernate, springframework

I am using JBOSS 5.1.0.GA, MySQL 5.5 and Hibernate 3.3.1 GA (included with JBOSS) + Spring.

My question is do I need to add c3p0 as a data source in my spring/hibernate configuration for connection pooling or are the setting in the JBOSS mysql-ds.xml setting enough.

My mysql-ds.xml is the following:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>MySqlDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecotrak</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>ecotrak</user-name>
    <password>ecotrak</password>
    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <!-- should only be used on drivers after 3.22.1 with "ping" support    -->
    <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>

    <!-- sql to call when connection is created
    <new-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</new-connection-sql>
      -->
    <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool - MySQLValidConnectionChecker is preferred for newer drivers
    <check-valid-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</check-valid-connection-sql>
      -->

    <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
    <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Answer (score 1):

JBoss DataSource has it's own connection pool, from spring application deployed on it just use jndi data source 
for example

http://pro-programmers.blogspot.com/2008/07/spring-datasource-jndi-lookup-from.html